# Javascript Url issue in new frame

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JavaScript issue. I am using it to open an HTML web page in a new frame with the following function:

```
function openBranch(url) {
  if (url == "Ping") {
    top.folderFrame.location = "Ping.html"
  } else if (url == "Logout") {
    top.top.location = "Logout.html"
  }
}
```

HTML usage:

```
<a href='javascript:openBranch("Ping")'>Ping</a>
```

I am unable to open another web page in my side menu bar once my `Ping.html` page is processed (Post request is used). My side menu bar is unable to open the new page and is not able to process any request.

Comment: why do you need a new frame?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the argument of the function changes the source of the document. If you want to just change the source, why don't you just do something like this:

```
<iframe src="test1.html" id="top"></iframe>
<a href="#" onclick="change(1)">change to 1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="change(2)">change to 2</a>


    <script>

        function change(val) {

            if (val === 1) {
                document.getElementById("top").src = "test1.html";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("top").src = "test2.html";
            }

        }

    </script>
```